# How to handle stale connections in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

It is possible to end up with stale connections in a connection pool that is servicing a JPA EntityManager. Upon using such a connection a [generic] exception is thrown, but what is a portable (non-vendor specific) way to determine if the connection is stale or not (and hence whether or not it should be retried)?

What I am looking for is the equivalent of the JDBC Connection.isValid() method.

Thanks

Comment: Normally you handle this using a "Test query" in your connection pool config.  However, this is vendor-specific.

Comment: typically your connection pool should take care of this. are you seeing such errors in your application? what connection pool are you using and how is it configured?

Comment: Unfortunately the connection pool is set up with 'test connection' disabled (and this is beyond my control) hence I was trying to code around it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EclipseLink, with EclipseLink's conneciton pooling it will automatically detect and reconnect dead connections on a communications failure.

If you are using a DataSource, then you really need to enable the connection in the DataSource for it to work.  Otherwise you have no way to expel a connection from the DataSource's pool, you could try to get another connection, but if the DataSource does not know the connection is dead, it may give you or other threads back the dead connection.